# Null Value Passing From View To Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Commodity Report View :

```
   @model PMEX.CSR.Models.ReportModel
   @{
     ViewBag.Title = "Commodity Report";
   }

   <div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @{
                    if (Model != null)
                    {
                    @Html.ActionLink("Download PDF Report", "DownloadReportPDF", Model);
                    }
                }
            </td>               
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
```

Report Controller cs File :

```
  public ActionResult DownloadReportPDF(ReportModel model)
    {
        // to do some stuff
        return View("Commodity");
    }
```

Report Model

```
 public class ReportModel
   {
    public string testValue { get; set; }

    public DataTable dt { get; set; }
    public LikeFilterModel LikeFilterModelObj { get; set; }
    // [Required]
    // public string SearchText { get; set; }
    public GridModels GridDataModel { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Represents that datagrid has rows in it.
    /// </summary>
    public bool isValue { get; set; }
    }
```

My model when i received on the view

[image]

Model which i am receiving on Controller through actionlink.

[image]

As you can see everything i receiving on controller is null. Please tell me what going wrong here ?

I want to pass the same model to the controller which i received on View.

Comment: Please see my answer below and comment explaining...

Answer (score 1):

`Html.ActionLink` is expecting to have `routeValues` instead of your object Model. Check the reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd493018(v=vs.118).aspx).

...

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass data to the controller in this manner, any data that comes from a view should be POSTed or passed along in the query string e.g.

```
if (Model != null)
{
    @using (Html.BeginForm("DownloadPDFReport", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Property1)
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Property2)
        ...
        <input type="submit" value="Download PDF Report" />
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not *required* to be posted.  It can be passed as QueryString parameters as GET.

Comment: Passing the model in as a route value object CAN pass the original values back to the controller as part of a GET.

Comment: @ErikPhilips yeah, I guess I was looking at the model and realising that there was probably no way a GET would work for this example.

Comment: still no help. return null in datatable

Comment: @ShujaatSiddiqui a `DataTable` is a fairly complex type, the likely hood of being able to post this back from the view is pretty slim. My advice would be rethink your view model and try to pass simple data or at least data that's simple enough to serialize.